# how can i limit or exclude logging for the test cases in springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, spring-data

We are getting a lot of logs from the test cases in travis and that's why all the test cases are not getting executed. Those tests are not even running. Need to remove the logs that the tests are producing. Any exclusions required in the test level? Can't eliminate the logs from code side. Please help.

using in pom:

```
    <groupId>gtd</groupId>
    <artifactId> spring-request-logger </artifactId>
    <version> RELEASE </version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Which logging framework are you using? Log4j2, logback or something else? [This](https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-test-how-to-stop-debug-logs/) link has some pointers for turning off unit test logging.

Comment: @Smile we are using logback. tried the link..not working. The logs are coming when we are building the project.

Comment: How do you build the project? Which command?

Comment: @Smile building the project using mvn -s settings.xml clean install from cmd